# How to move a Daily Partition to a Monthly Partitioned Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, partitioning

I would like to switch out a partition from a daily partitioned table and merge it into monthly partitioned table.  I am unsure as to how to go about it.  Here's what I have so far.

I have two tables, *Event_Daily* and *Event_Archive_Monthly*.  Both tables are partitioned on *CreatedDate datetime* with Event_Daily being partitioned by Day and Event_Archive_Monthly being partitioned by Month.

Event_Archive_Monthly has the following file groups:

- Archive_Monthly_2018_05_01_FG
- Archive_Monthly_2018_06_01_FG
- Archive_Monthly_2018_07_01_FG

Event_Daily has the following file groups:

- Daily_L_NULL_FG
- Daily_2018_06_18_FG
- Daily_2018_06_19_FG

I have 9 records in Event_Daily in the 2018_06_18 file group and no data on the other partitions.  I have created a *SwitchOut* table on Daily_2018_06_18_FG  and have issued these commands to switch out the data and merge the boundary point:

```
PRINT 'switching out previous days data'

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Event_Daily]
SWITCH PARTITION 2 TO dbo.Event_Daily_SwitchOut;
GO

PRINT 'merging boundary point'

ALTER PARTITION FUNCTION Daily_PF ()
    MERGE RANGE ( '2018-06-18' )
GO
```

At this point I am unsure as to how to get this data into the archive table.  Ideally, after everything is said and done the file group Daily_2018_06_18_FG is gone.  One option I know I have is to just insert the data and then drop the SwitchOut table and drop the file group.

**Is there a way, using the Partitioned Table, to merge the SwitchOut table that is on the filegroup Daily_2018_06_18_FG into the partition on Archive_Monthly_2018_06_01_FG?**

Answer (score 1):

*<sub>[Community wiki answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki):</sub>*

> Is there a way, using the Partitioned Table, to merge the SwitchOut table that is on the filegroup Daily_2018_06_18_FG into the partition on Archive_Monthly_2018_06_01_FG?

No, you'll need to use `INSERT...SELECT` for row processing. `MERGE/SPLIT/SWITCH` DDL are partition level.